# sql NOT LIKE "%term%" mot working

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, join, left-join

I have a query, it's a wordpress query for the custom search and it works fine, but here is some membership subscription and the users can't find the post if the forum is only for "gold" subscriptions

And now it shows all posts (free and gold) for all users
I wanna to modify query to something like display all except `AND (post_forum_meta.meta_value NOT LIKE '%gold%')`

I'm joined the post meta of the posts parent forum by id and then looking for meta_value (for free/for gold)

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
DISTINCT wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as meta_1 ON wp_posts.ID = meta_1.post_id 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as event_venue_meta ON meta_1.meta_value = event_venue_meta.post_id

LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as post_forum_meta ON meta_1.meta_value = post_forum_meta.post_id AND meta_1.meta_key='_bbp_forum_id'

LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships as tax_relation ON wp_posts.ID =  tax_relation.object_id
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy as tax_term ON tax_term.term_taxonomy_id = tax_relation.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN wp_terms as term ON term.term_id = tax_term.term_id 
LEFT  JOIN wp_icl_translations t


ON wp_posts.ID = t.element_id
AND t.element_type = CONCAT('post_', wp_posts.post_type)  
WHERE 1=1  
AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%search%')
AND (post_forum_meta.meta_value NOT LIKE '%gold%')
OR (meta_1.meta_key='_tribe_event_speaker' AND meta_1.meta_value LIKE '%search%')
OR (meta_1.meta_key='_EventStartDate' AND meta_1.meta_value LIKE '%search%')
OR (event_venue_meta.meta_key='_VenueAddress' AND event_venue_meta.meta_value LIKE '%search%')
OR (term.name LIKE '%search%')
OR (wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%search%') 
OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%search%')

))  
AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'tribe_events', 'topic') 
AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) 
AND ( ( t.language_code = 'de' AND wp_posts.post_type  IN ('post','page','forum','product','product_variation','tribe_venue','tribe_organizer','tribe_events','tribe_wooticket' )  ) );
```

I have tried with NULL LIKE NOT etc but no

so what I need it's to get all except "gold" posts...
Here are my tables:

[image: post to hide from search]
[image: post parent forum with capability]

Comment: AND and OR without brackets - always leads to problems

Answer (score 0):

Just move the condition up into your join:

```
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as post_forum_meta ON meta_1.meta_value = post_forum_meta.post_id AND 
    meta_1.meta_key='_bbp_forum_id' AND
    post_forum_meta.meta_value NOT LIKE '%gold%'
```

That will exclude the "gold" items from the dataset completely and will simplify the conditional statements at the bottom.

Alternatively, you could use parentheses to set the precedent of operations in the WHERE clause. It works just like basic math - remember "PEMDAS"?

```
WHERE 1=1  
  AND (
    (
      (
        wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%search%'
        AND post_forum_meta.meta_value NOT LIKE '%gold%'
      )
      AND (
        (meta_1.meta_key='_tribe_event_speaker' AND meta_1.meta_value LIKE '%search%')
        OR (meta_1.meta_key='_EventStartDate' AND meta_1.meta_value LIKE '%search%')
        OR (event_venue_meta.meta_key='_VenueAddress' AND event_venue_meta.meta_value LIKE '%search%')
        OR (term.name LIKE '%search%')
        OR (wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%search%') 
        OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%search%')
      )
    )
    AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'tribe_events', 'topic') 
    AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
    AND (
      t.language_code = 'de' 
      AND wp_posts.post_type  IN ('post','page','forum','product','product_variation','tribe_venue','tribe_organizer','tribe_events','tribe_wooticket')
    )
  );
```

You just need to make sure that the condition you want to exclude is properly nested inside the correct set of parens. Right now, your "NOT LIKE" statement is being overridden by one of those "OR" conditions.

You might find it more performant to use the first option I mentioned above - joining smaller sets of data can lead to a more performant query.

Comment: Thanks, man, but when I modify like that I get ONLY "gold" 
Any ideas?

Comment: @anper you get ONLY "gold"? That's odd because the statement says "NOT LIKE". What is the actual value that you're looking for in that field? Is it a single value, or is it a comma-delimited list of values in that column?

Answer (score 0):

`AND(((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%search%')
 AND(post_forum_meta.meta_value NOT LIKE '%gold%')`

Try **<>** instead

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

After the chat with this guy, query become

```
SELECT p.ID, GROUP_CONCAT(m2.meta_key SEPARATOR " ") as is_paid
FROM wp_posts  p
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS m1 ON p.ID = m1.post_id 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as event_venue_meta ON m1.meta_value = event_venue_meta.post_id
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS m2 ON m1.meta_value = m2.post_id AND m1.meta_key = '_bbp_forum_id'
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS m3 ON m2.post_id = m3.post_id AND m3.meta_key = 'groups-groups_read_post'
LEFT  JOIN wp_icl_translations t ON p.ID = t.element_id AND t.element_type = CONCAT('post_', p.post_type)  
WHERE p.post_title LIKE '%search%'
GROUP BY p.ID
HAVING is_paid NOT LIKE "%groups-groups_read_post%" OR is_paid IS NULL
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the trick, it's work!!! I have changed a bit, and now it returns right results. Thanks!!